# Filter FeedItems by community in SOQL

Tags: apex, community, feeditem

Is there any way, we can filter FeedItems by Community in SOQL? Currently, it doesn't support filtering by NetworkScope

Comment: what do you mean, doesn't support filtering by NetworkScope?,  what api version are you using, the documentation states that it does starting api version 26 and if salesforce communities is enabled, can you provide more context?

Comment: Looks like there are a few people wondering the same thing here. I see you already posted an inquiry there as an answer. Hopefully someone can figure it out!